"De-singularize" an improper integral
Consider the improper integral
$$
\int_0^\pi \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(\cos(x)+1+a)(\cos(x)+1)}},
$$
for some $a>0$.
Does anyone know of a change of variables substitution that would make this integral proper, that is an integral on a finite interval on which the integrand is bounded?
Before you evaluate this integral explicitly for me, please consider the reason why I am asking this question. The integral above is part of a family of close or similar integrals that I am evaluating with "interval arithmetics", using software that "dislikes singularities". I believe the other integrals will be "de-singularized" as well if I find a way to do it for the simplest of my examples, the one written above.

The function $\sqrt{1+\cos x}=\sqrt2\cos\frac{x}{2}$ has asymptotics at $x=\pi$ as $\text{const}\cdot (\pi-x)$, which is a non-summable singularity. The integral is divergent to $+\infty$.

@A.Γ. Thanks. I really do not know how I did not see this before.

The integral is divergent as @A.Γ. pointed out in his/her comment above. So that answers the question.
